# Any one with experience on X-Author for Excel by apttus?

Tags: managed-package

we have created the template for exporting account data in excel using X-Author for excel (appexchange product), but it is giving error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and also where can we see the X-Author log file?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, that package is paid. Just ask tech support

Comment: Sounds like a question for Apttus. If you paid for the product, they're likely willing to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The following are the steps for seeing log file

1. Click show hidden icons button.
2. Right Click X-author for Excel
3. it show two log file(Product log and Save log)
4. Select any one of the above log file.

Answer (score 0):

In our case we had to remove office version not used under reg key Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\
You will see multiple versions, "1.9", "1.8", "1.7". Remove the extra entries for the version not used.